# How to utilise the back button handler on Microsoft Teams sdk

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to be able to utilise the back button in the teams tab config wizard, similar to the on save handler defined below, that works as expected for the save button.

```
function registerOnSaveHandler(handler: (evt: SaveEvent) => void)
```

Controls the save button shown here :

[image: teams tab config wizard]

Although, I can't find the applicable handler for back. If it doesn't exist, then why are we even shown the back button? As it currently has the same use as the close (x) at the top right.

Has anyone been able to use this? and if so, how?

There is a [registerOnRemoveHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/using-teams-client-sdk) handler documented, but unsure if this can be used for the back button.

Comment: I don't think there's a handler to enable you to hook into this - it's just provided as a UI option to the user, not for your app to use, afaik. In addition, the "remove" capabilities are for you to be able to be notified the user is removing your tab such that you can remove any database resource as appropriate, for example - it's definitely not the same as "back" per se

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow I was thinking that might be the case. Very unfortunate as it would have been really nice to have that capability. Thanks for the summary on registerOnRemoveHandler too. Appreciate it.

Comment: out of interest, what would you be wanting to do on "back"?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow I have a wizard that helps create a link for the tab that's added, it has different routes depending on the users input and I've had to create a back button for navigating the wizard. Shame not being able to use the one included.

Comment: ahh ok, sounds like a really interesting use case. How are they interacting with the wizard itself? Is it a web experience?